# IIS Performance Issue

Tags: performance, iis

Environment: Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8.5

I have been observing slow performing transactions during load tests even if CPU utilization was < 60% and Memory utilization < 50% . I tried the following settings on IIS Manager, but No improvement was observed.

Threads Per Processor Limit - Increased from 25 to 50

minBytesPerSecond - Reduced from 240 to 0

Max Worker Processes - Increased from 1 to 2 and 5

Please help me with any other IIS settings that my improve performance.

Comment: perhaps the bottleneck is DB or network..

Comment: What kind of web app? Use a performance profiler to identify the bottleneck first. Blindly changing IIS settings won't help at all.

Comment: DB is not a problem. I have a breakdown of response time for a call, it took 200 milli seconds in (App+DB), the same call showing 10 seconds in IIS logs. I guess the bottleneck is within IIS. Please share your thoughts and inputs.